# How use Any object in kotlin parceable?

Tags: android, kotlin, any

I have to use Any Object for parseable in kotlin data model.

```
@Parcelize
data class TestModel(

     var data: ArrayList<Any>? = null

) : Parcelable
```

android studio show below error.
[image]

I add @RawValue in the data class

```
var data: @RawValue ArrayList<Any>? = null
```

but when I create a new instance from class, I get this error
[image]

anybody can help me?

Comment: `Any` is not Parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable this feature in the gradle file:

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

also make sure you applied the plugin of kotlin extension for android:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

[Enabling experimental features](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#enabling-experimental-features)